# Update the fastlane version on Circle CI

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, circleci, fastlane

I am in the process of upgrading an outdated application to all of the latest versions of SDK's and one of the parts was quite a complex build- and signing process using fastlane and Circle CI. Everything works except the last part where the built output gets pushed to the iTunes App Store. I've noticed that around WWDC the interface changed and fastlane needed an update to 1.150 or higher to work with that new API. The instance of Circle CI seems stuck at something like 1.138 and shell scripts to try to update it don't seem to work because of security limitations.

What is the official approach to get the latest version of `fastlane` in Circle CI?

---

Content of the `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'fastlane'
```

---

In a shell script:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if "offical", but I'd recommend to use `bundle`.

Add a `Gemfile` to your project like so:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "fastlane"
```

run `bundle update`, and add the resulting `Gemfile.lock` to your version control. Now invoke fastlane using `bundle exec fastlane ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I've added my Gemfile for clarity. Except for the (probably unrelated) cocoapods line it's the same. Trying the `bundle update` call now. Let's see what happened in about 10 minutes.

Comment: So you put me into the right direction. I had to locally run `bundle update`, then check in the resulting `.lockfile`. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad it helped.